# Addin is not able to see in outlook

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I have created outlook add in plugin but not able to see on tabs

When I run the application add in added under the Active application add ins list, but not able to see on tabs

[these are](https://timdams.com/2017/05/09/how-to-create-a-simple-outlook-vsto-addin-a-step-by-step-guide/) the steps I am following

Below are code snippet,

ThisAddIn.cs

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //myUserControl1 = new UserControl();

        //myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1, "View AddIn");
        //myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Ribbon.cs

```
public partial class Ribbon
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("AddIn is opened");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does ThisAddIn_Startup() fire? Can you put a breakpoint there?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko yes, its fire..

Comment: Then something is wrong with your ribbon XML. Please provide more details on your ribbon customization.